# how to add country code list in mobile number input field in laravel

Tags: input, laravel-8, ajaxform, country-codes, mobile-country-code

I am new to Laravel so I don't know how to add country code list in mobile number input field in Laravel using Ajax.

I tried some code with the help of ChatGPT but nothing happened.  I want a country code list in mobile number input field:
[image: this is the form screenshot]

Also describe how to submit this form using Ajax with message.

Comment: When you say country code, do you mean country code for mobile numbers listed and can be used as a select drop down?

Comment: Quick google search will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645925